# 'SKControl' does not contain a definition for 'Canvas'

Tags: c#, skiasharp

I'm trying to make a game engine but im having errors that SKControl doesnt have a def for Canvas!
Here's the full error: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'SKControl' does not contain a definition for 'Canvas' and no accessible extension method 'Canvas' accepting a first argument of type 'SKControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  RING2D  C:\Users\Radek\source\repos\RING2D\Editor.cs    147 Active

I tried putting the error into chatgpt but it would just repeat what i was saying, i expected when you are over the object and drag it to the SKControl object it will paint the object where the mouse last was when you released, and i have an error!

My Code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SkiaSharp;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Desktop;

namespace RING2D
{
    public partial class Editor : Form
    {
        private SKControl skControl;
        private int width, height;
        private bool isDragging;
        private SKPoint lastPosition = SKPoint.Empty;

        public Editor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Get the SKControl from the form's controls
            skControl = Controls.OfType<SKControl>().FirstOrDefault();

            if (skControl != null)
            {
                // Store the initial width and height
                width = skControl.Width;
                height = skControl.Height;

                // Set up the paint surface event handler
                skControl.PaintSurface += OnPaintSurface;
            }

            // Set up the mouse event handlers for the blueCircle object
            blueCircle.MouseDown += blueCircle_MouseDown;
            blueCircle.MouseMove += blueCircle_MouseMove;
            blueCircle.MouseUp += blueCircle_MouseUp;
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "Ring Projects (*.ring)|*.ring";
            openFileDialog.Title = "Open Ring File";


            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
                // Open and read the file here
            }

        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog.Filter = "Ring Projects (*.ring)|*.ring";
            saveFileDialog.Title = "Save Ring File As";

            if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void toolStripMenuItem9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var BuildSettings = new Build();
            BuildSettings.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OnPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;

            canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

            using (var paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 255);
                canvas.DrawCircle(100, 100, 50, paint);
            }
        }

        private void blueCircle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the mouse is being dragged
            if (isDragging)
            {
                // Convert the mouse position to a SKPoint
                SKPoint position = new SKPoint(e.X, e.Y);

                // Move the blue circle by the delta between the current and last positions
                blueCircle.Left += (int)(position.X - lastPosition.X);
                blueCircle.Top += (int)(position.Y - lastPosition.Y);

                // Update the last position to the current position
                lastPosition = position;
            }
        }
        private void blueCircle_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the left mouse button was pressed
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                // Convert the mouse position to a SKPoint
                SKPoint position = new SKPoint(e.X, e.Y);

                // Check if the mouse is under the blue circle
                if (IsUnderObject(blueCircle, position))
                {
                    // Set the dragging flag to true and store the last position
                    isDragging = true;
                    lastPosition = position;
                }
            }
        }

        private void blueCircle_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            // Check if the left mouse button was released and the blue circle was being dragged
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && isDragging)
            {
                // Draw a blue circle at the last mouse position using SKControl and SKiaSharp
                using (var paint = new SKPaint())
                {
                    paint.Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 255);

                    // Get the canvas from the SKControl
                    SKCanvas canvas = skControl.Canvas;

                    // Convert the last position to screen coordinates
                    Point screenPosition = PointToScreen(new Point((int)lastPosition.X, (int)lastPosition.Y));

                    // Convert the screen position to client coordinates relative to the canvas
                    Point canvasPosition = skControl.PointToClient(screenPosition);

                    // Draw the blue circle on the canvas
                    canvas.DrawCircle(canvasPosition.X, canvasPosition.Y, 50, paint);

                    // Invalidate the SKControl to trigger a repaint
                    skControl.Invalidate();

                    // Reset the dragging flag
                    isDragging = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool IsUnderObject(Control control, SKPoint position)
        {
            // Convert the control's location and size to a SKRect
            SKRect rect = new SKRect(control.Left, control.Top, control.Right, control.Bottom);

            // Check if the position is inside the SKRect
            return rect.Contains(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must do all the drawing inside `OnPaintSurface`. In `MouseUp` store all the relevant data in class fields and then call `skControl.Invalidate();`. This will trigger `OnPaintSurface`.